# Throwing an Exception on every application error

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I have an application based on Zend Framwork. In one Model I am calling a method from another Model. When I call this method I use try-cath block for handling of strange situations.
Model1.

```
try {
   $result  =  Module_Model2_Name->method();
} catch (Exception $e) {
   // Do Something
}
```

Catch should be work if we find a throw in try block. But I don't know about behaviour of my application. If it is a some application error in Model2 method it should be throw an Exception.
In method of Model2 I do the next thing, but it doesn't work:

```
set_error_handler(create_function('$m = "Error"','throw new Exception($m);'), E_ALL);
```

How can I throw an Exception on every PHP application error?
Thank you very much. Sorry for my English.

Comment: +1 to correct two stupid, unexplained and unnecessary downvotes. I sincerely hope they're not for the english.

Comment: @Shabbyrobe I'm pretty sure they were because the question was correctly answered and the OP downvoted the obviously correct answer with a simple 'It isn't an answer'. If that wasn't the answer, then this was a *really* bad question. Of course the OP has now accepted that answer.

Comment: Edited to allow vote changing since the OP has since accepted the answer he downvoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks good to me (tested it).

```
<?php
set_error_handler(create_function('$nr, $msg = "Error"','throw new Exception($m);'), E_ALL);
try{
    foreach($notHere as $var){}
}
catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($e);
}
?>
```

Please note that:

> The following error types cannot be
>   handled with a user defined function:
>   E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR,
>   E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR,
>   E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of
>   E_STRICT raised in the file where
>   set_error_handler() is called.

*Taken from the PHP manual.*

Comment: -1. It isn't an answer. I know this part of manual. It isn't help me.

Comment: Please explain then what do you want to do? This example works good. PHP throws an exception every time PHP error occures.

Comment: Beg your pardon? What else would you need? You asked: *How can I throw an Exception on every PHP application error?* and I gave you a code snippet that does that. I also pointed out that some errors can't be caught with an error handler by giving you a quote from the manual.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru: You missed error number param. Should be: `set_error_handler(create_function('$nr, $msg = "Default error message"','throw new Exception("$msg);'), E_ALL);`

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: One more typo to fix ;)

Answer (score 4):

My version:

```
function custom_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
    $constants = get_defined_constants(1);

    $eName = 'Unknown error type';
    foreach ($constants['Core'] as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 2) == 'E_' && $errno == $value) {
            $eName = $key;
            break;
        }
    }

    $msg = $eName . ': ' . $errstr . ' in ' . $errfile . ', line ' . $errline;

    throw new Exception($msg);
}

set_error_handler('custom_error_handler', E_ALL);
```